# Hover over doesn't work when two items are in different divs?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, hover, jsx

I want to hover over and show the text but text and logo are in the different div but when I hover over, it doesn't show the text.

```
import styles from '../styles/Float.module.css'
export default function COnnection(){
    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>

        <div className={styles.float}>

            <a href="https://github.com/YasamanForouzesh" target="_blank">
                <img className={styles.github} src="/GitHub.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 className={`${styles["h1"]} ${styles["githubT"]}`}>GitHub</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I also tried display: none and display:block but it still doesn't work and it doesn't show text when I hover the logo

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.float {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(112, 100, 200);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 40px;
}

.github {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  grid-row: 2;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.githubT {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.github:hover .githubT {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

here is my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-violet-nklue?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using a parent selector to select the `.githubT` class when the `.github` class is hovered. When you select elements with the syntax: `.class1 .class2` you are selecting all elements with class2 that are descendants of class1.

Try putting the :hover pseudo class on your anchor tag and selecting `.githubT` using something like this:

```css
a:hover+.githubT {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

(selects an element that comes immediately after the first element).

Comment: .float:hover + .githubT {
      visibility: visible;
    }

Try using this code, @YasamanForouzesh

Comment: @BilalMohammad It doesn't work. it is so weird

Comment: @YasamanForouzesh I created a sandbox , and it works there, https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-resonance-3k84p

Comment: @BilalMohammad Because your code has just one element in first div and you point to whole div but for mine has three elements in first div and each element should show different things so I should point to each element separately.

Comment: @BilalMohammad I created sandbox too that maybe can help more https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-violet-nklue?file=/Float.module.css

Comment: @YasamanForouzesh In your sandbox the ~ selector can't find the ```.github``` class because it is the child of an anchor element. Select the anchor element instead and it will work.